# creating a DLL file using C++

Tags: c++, c, dll

I'm a newbie in C/C++ programming and I need to create a dll file so that the algorithmic model can interact with another program that call it. I wrote a empty function with function prototypes and dummy return values both in C and C++ and compiled them in gcc and g++ respectively. The dll file generated from C file easily integrated with the Parent program and returned required output. However, for the C++, the program says could not locate the **initialise** function. The code structure in both the files is as:

```
void initialise (int a) {
   return 1;
}
void body (int b) {
   return 1;
}
void close () {
   return 1;
}
```

compilation method (using mingw gcc and g++ respectively)

```
gcc -c test.c
gcc -shared -o test1.dll test.o

g++ -c test.c
g++ -shared -o test2.dll test.o
```

I would be needing cpp for proceeding with my project, so can't use c. How can I compile the dll using C so as to remove this error from occurring? Also please mention what difference in compilation between C and C++ is causing this issue?

Comment: C != C++. C++ has [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Handling_of_C_symbols_when_linking_from_C.2B.2B). If your caller of the DLL is expecting C, you need to code the C++ specifically so that works.

Comment: RTFM: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampledll

Answer (score 0):

try: extern "c" __declspec( dllimport )